# error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies - RN iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, autolink

I'm new to React native. I get the following error when I try to start the project in the ios simulator. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of React Native have autolinking, therefore you don't need to run commands like `npx react-native link some-package-name` to link the dependencies

In order to get rid of this error you need to unlink the dependency mentioned in the log, use the following instructions

1. Run `npx react-native unlink @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`
2. Run `npm uninstall @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`
3. Run `npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage`
4. Change to the ios directory `cd ios` and run `pod install`

That should solve this issue